# How to differentiate between a 32bit and 24bit bmp file? Also how do I read a 32bit bmp file into a C++ array?

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp

I wasn't able to find any difference between bmp files available online, so that I could easily tell whether they were 24 or 32 bit.

I need to read a 32 bit bmp file into rgb array using C++ and most tutorials exist only for 32 bit.

Comment: The *biBitCount* member of the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229.aspx) structure declares the number of bits per pixel. If you need to read a bitmap file, use a library. On Windows that would be the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx). Don't roll your own. The BMP file format is **way** too complex.

Comment: @IInspectable Is there no way to create my own structures to deal with headers and other garbage data since my main work is with rgb values? Using WIC seems more complex than easy, frankly speaking.

Comment: @Anurag do you develop with windows and hope for a shorter way than learning WIC ?  Or do you ask because you're working cross platform ?

Comment: Of course it's possible to write your own file parser. But it is a lot more demanding, than you think. You have to discern between 24 and 32 bit image formats, different compression schemes, calculate the image size yourself (taking scanline alignment into account), read the image data at the correct offset. And then you have to deal with BMPs, that violate the file format specification (many do, namely bitmaps stored in Photoshop). WIC may look complex, but writing your own file format parser is a lot more challenging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The format of bitmap files is described [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391(v=vs.85).aspx): it starts with a file header of 14 bytes, followed by a [bitmap info header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx), which contains the information you're looking for in the field `biBitCount`.

***Edit:***

As noted by iinspectable in the comments, the bitmap format can be complex.  So with Windows, the best is to access to the information of the structures described above using the windows API.

If you're working cross platform, you'll have to take care yourself of many details:

- the different [file format versions](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm):  In fact you need to read the `DWORD` (32 bits unsigned) at offset 14 of the file to find out [which version of the data structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183386(v=vs.85).aspx) is used.  The information you're looking fore is at offset 24 (core version) or 28 (other versions) of the file.  It's a [`WORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), so it's 16 bits unsigned.
- the file format could be compressed.  This is not the case for the core version.  For the other versions, it's indicated in the following `DWORD` (at offset 30).
- all integers are stored in little endian.

But instead of doing all this by yourself, you could as well consider [CImg](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__files__io.html) or another library.

Comment: You are mistaken. The [BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374.aspx) might be followed by a [BITMAPCOREINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183373.aspx). In that case, the offset of *bcBitCount* would be 24. As I said, don't roll your own. BMPs are **radically** complex.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for pointing this out.  I've edited accordingly.